# Clustering algorithm with different epsilons on different axes

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, dbscan, elki

I am looking for a clustering algorithm such a s DBSCAN do deal with 3d data, in which is possible to set different epsilons depending on the axis. So for instance an epsilon of 10m on the x-y plan, and an epsilon 0.2m on the z axis.

Essentially, I am looking for large but flat clusters.

Note: I am an archaeologist, the algorithm will be used to look for potential correlations between objects scattered in large surfaces, but in narrow vertical layers

Comment: Also, I am working primarily with ELKI

Comment: Could you just apply a transformation to your data before and after clustering?

Comment: Hyo, yes that's an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

Scale your data set to match your desired epsilon.

In your case, scale z by 50.

### Solution 2:

Use a weighted distance function.

E.g. [WeightedEuclideanDistanceFunction](http://elki.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/releases/release0.6.5~20141030/doc/de/lmu/ifi/dbs/elki/distance/distancefunction/minkowski/WeightedEuclideanDistanceFunction.html) in ELKI, and choose your weights accordingly, e.g. `-distance.weights 1,1,50` will put 50x as much weight on the third axis.

This may be the most convenient option, since you are already using ELKI.

Comment: Than you very much! this WeightedEuclideanDistanceFunction in Elki is exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Just define a custom distance metric when computing the [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) core points. The standard DBSCAN uses the [Euclidean distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) to compute points within an epsilon. So all dimensions are treated the same.

However, you could use the [Mahalanobis distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance) to weigh each dimension differently. You can use a diagonal covariance matrix for flat clusters. You can use a full symmetric covariance matrix for flat tilted clusters, etc.

In your case, you would use a covariance matrix like:

<kbd>100</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>    <kbd>0</kbd>   
  <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>100</kbd>  <kbd>0</kbd>   
  <kbd>0</kbd>    <kbd>0</kbd>  <kbd>0.04</kbd>

In the pseudo code provided at the Wikipedia entry for [DBSCAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN) just use one of the distance metrics suggested above in the **regionQuery** function.

**Update**

Note: scaling the data is equivalent to using an appropriate metric.