# Using the Weighted Euclidean Distance Function for DBSCAN in ELKI

Tags: euclidean-distance, dbscan, elki

I'm experimenting with ELKI (which is awesome, btw) and would like to try the weighted Euclidean distance function as a metric for the DBSCAN algorithm.

First of all, I don't know how it works, except for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073628/clustering-algorithm-with-different-epsilons-on-different-axes).

I tried a few values for the parameter distance.weights. If I insert for example 3,1 in its field, this is what I get after I hit ENTER:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm still able to run the task but I see no difference in the results, no matter the values I insert.

Could anyone please provide a short explanation on how the function works and eventually what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since 1*x=x, a weight of 1 does not change anything. Weights are linear scaling factors.

Comment: Hi Erich! It was just to illustrate, but I admit it was a bad example. I edited and changed the values. Is it normal that I get 1.0,0.0 after hitting ENTER?

Comment: If you enter "1,0" then yes. The default double formatter will format 1 as 1.0. Weight 0 = ignore that column. Depending on your data, the second column may simply have no influence, then changing the weight won't change the result. What data do you use?

Comment: Actually in the example above I entered 3,1. My data has two columns, x and y, representing coordinates in the Cartesian plane.

Comment: It should not turn 3,1 into 1,0; there probably was a bug a year ago in the function converting this back to a string (I have a vague memory of a off-by-one bug in the rarely used double-list parameter class). But this does not happen for me anymore in the Git version, please use the latest code instead.